# insert open and close tags at the positions corresponding to a list of tups

Tags: python, html, string, list, tags

I have to mark up a text inserting tags in a string as follows:

```
mystring = '123456789'
postions = [(2,4),(6,8)]

result = '12<tag1>34</tag1>56<tag2>78</tag2>9'
```

positions is a list of tuples that gives the start and end of the tag.
(In principle the spans of the tags do not overlap)

I started assumend that I would need all the positions of the tags flatten out:

```
import itertools
pos2 = list(itertools.chain(*positions))
```

which gives:

```
[2, 4, 6, 8]
```

That allows me to do this:

```
stringWithTags= ''
opentag=True
nrtag=1
for j,character in enumerate(mystring):
    i=j+1
    if i in pos2:
        if opentag:
            toadd = character + '<tag' + str(nrtag) +'>' 
        else:
            toadd = character + '</tag' + str(nrtag) +'>'  
            nrtag = nrtag + 1
        
        stringWithTags = stringWithTags + toadd
        opentag = not(opentag)
        
    else:
        stringWithTags = stringWithTags + character

stringWithTags
```

that works, but its quite horrible code, and incredible verbose.
This problem should be well known and there might be out of the box solutions I am not aware of.

Any suggestions?

EDIT 1: I also considered my code not water tight because the moment the spans overlap this will not fly and a solution valid in both cases

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that easy way is to split string to list and work with it by indexes from positions like this: split string, loop over positions-list, add prefix tag or suffix tag by position, finally join list to new string.

```
mystring = '123456789'
postions = [(2,4),(6,8)]

str_list = [c for c in mystring]
for r in postions:
    for _, c in enumerate(r):
        str_list[c] = ('</tag>{}' if _ else '<tag>{}').format(str_list[c])
new_string = ''.join(str_list)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
mystring = list('123456789')
postions = [(2,4),(6,8)]

shift = 0
for pos in postions:
    tag = "<tag>"
    mystring.insert(pos[0] + shift, tag)
    shift += 1
    mystring.insert(pos[1] + shift, tag.replace('<', '</'))
    shift += 1
print(''.join(mystring))
```

output: `12<tag>34</tag>56<tag>78</tag>9`

you can write more code for tag variable. I just wrote a sample.

Answer (score 1):

assuming the tags are listed in order and they don't cross each other what you could do is :

```
mystring = '123456789'
positions = [(2,4),(6,8)]
reversed_position = reversed(positions)
nb_tags = len(postions)

for tup in reversed_position:
    mystring = mystring[:tup[1]]+f"</tag{nb_tags}>"+mystring[tup[1]:]
    mystring = mystring[:tup[0]]+f"<tag{nb_tags}>"+mystring[tup[0]:]
    nb_tags-=1
```

`mystring == result` returns True